# Get extra user fields from Joomla [protected rows]

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, field

Im using this plugin http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin to create extra fields in user register at my page which is supporting with Joomla 2.5.x

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);
var_dump($profile);

$article->text .= $pro1file->profile['field'];
```

but i have this error:

```
object(JObject)#386 (3) { ["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } ["id"]=> string(2) "45" ["profile5"]=> array(7) { ["imie"]=> string(5) "Dawid" ["something2"]=> string(8) "Górecki" ["firma"]=> string(6) "DG ZHU" ["nip"]=> string(9) "123456789" ["telefon"]=> string(9) "500500500" ["ulica"]=> string(6) "ogrody" ["miejscowosc"]=> string(9) "ostrowiec" } }
```

anybody now what its all about? I cant figure this out from a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: wht is $pro1file-> ? just comment $article->text .= $pro1file->profile['field']; and print the array

Comment: It's just typo. I'm sorry, my mistake. Anyway, still have got problem. Any ideas?

Comment: what error its getting the code you shown is var_dump($profile) right ? that have proper data ?

Comment: @DawidGórecki - If you have made a typo, please update your question with any corrections

Comment: Seriously dude, that's not an error it's the output of the `var_dump($profile);` line.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error (once you fix your typo):

```
$article->text .= $pro1file->profile['field'];
```

should read for example

```
$article->text .= "<br>" . $profile->profile['imie'] . "(" . $profile->profile['telefon'] . ")";
```

(You were querying the field "field" which is not part of the custom fields you created).

btw just one suggestion: make a rule of using english for field names, other developers will be able to help you.